# What does it mean to "take from the community and never give back"?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

[This](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) page about suspensions uses some vague language and I am curious as to what it means by:

> The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would include

- getting an answer and immediately deleting the question (before it can be upvoted)
- morphing your questions into something else once they have been answered

Accepting answers is a good way of giving back too. Nobody expects you to accept all your answers, or even most of them but perhaps if you've asked a number of questions and never bothered to accept any of the answers to even one of them...

Comment: I don't think anyone could accuse me of taking without giving back (I think I've awarded 5 bounties in the past two weeks).  I was just curious.  I haven't deleted any questions unless I realized they were duplicates or discovered the answer on my own immediately after I asked them.